# How to add an image to shopify using liquid?

Tags: image, upload, addition, shopify, liquid

I am new to this and there are barely any tutorials for liquid, unlike PHP.

Here's what I want to do.

Create a simple box on a page and being able to upload an image into that box, from the theme settings area.

How would I go on about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Shopify wiki page on [settings.html](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/theme-development/templates/settings):

> The `settings.html` file is rendered on the Theme Settings page of the Shopify Admin.

To upload an image in Theme Settings, you want the [File Upload input type](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/theme-development/templates/settings#input-types):

> **File upload**
>   Useful for uploading assets to a theme, such as logo images, favicons, and slideshow images...
>
> ```
> <tr>
>     <th>
>         <label for="my_file">File Upload</label>
>     </th>
>     <td>
>         <input type="file" name="logo.png" data-max-width="500" data-max-height="300" />
>     </td>
> </tr>
> ```
>
> Files uploaded through `settings.html` are placed in the theme's **assets** folder. The name of the saved file is not determined by the original file, but rather by the `name` attribute of the file input tag. For example, the file uploaded through the example above would be saved as **logo.png**. Furthermore, Shopify will convert the image to the type specified in the `name` attribute.

Then you can access the uploaded file via Liquid as you would normally access assets. For example:

```
  <a id="logo" href="/" role="banner">
    {{ 'logo.png' | asset_url | img_tag: shop.name }}
  </a>
```

Comment: That is great. It works.  Mind I ask you how you would add the delete button in settings.html to remove the uploaded image?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know if you can delete an uploaded image from Theme Settings (it's stored in the assets directory). I would suggest adding a checkbox called something like "Use image?" and only show the uploaded file if the checkbox is ticked. E.g. `{% if settings.use_image %}...{% endif %}`. See this tutorial ([Part 1](http://www.tetchi.ca/shopify-theme-from-scratch-part-14/) & [Part 2](http://www.tetchi.ca/shopify-theme-from-scratch-part-15/)) for more info on theme settings.